# What is the best way to aggregate a library of windows forms utilities?

Tags: winforms

I am writing a number of windows forms that require shared functionality.
For example, I want to use the following font-resizing utility in several forms:

```
static public Font ChangeFontSize( Font font, float fontSize )
{
   if (font != null)
   {
       float currentSize = font.Size;  
       if (currentSize != fontSize)  
       {
           font = new Font( font.Name, fontSize,
                            font.Style, font.Unit,
                            font.GdiCharSet, font.GdiVerticalFont );
       }
   }
   return font;
}
```

(taken from C# 441, http://www.csharp411.com/change-font-size/)

What is the best way to aggregate functions like this into a common library that can be shared between many forms? I started to put the into a C# class library, but of course these don't expose any drawing/UI functions.

Just so I am clear - I am not asking about the suitability of the above function, but the best way to aggregate such functions in a way they can be shared between many windows forms.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Why can't a class library include drawing/UI functions? Just add reference to System.Windows.Forms and you can do UI stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about a class library.  There certainly isn't any need to *not* include drawing or UI helper methods.  The only possible speed bump is that the project template doesn't automatically include the assembly references that you'll need.

Project + Add Reference, pick at least System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms.